# Setting the criteria for node splitting in a Decision Tree

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, lightgbm

I want to give a custom metric that should be optimised to decide while split to use for a decision tree, to replace the standard 'gini index'. How can I do this in any Decision Tree package. Could be boosted decesion trees.

Edit:
I want to implement a criterion like:

```
crit = (c1 + c2 - c3)/(2* sqrt(c2 + c4))
```

where c1,c2,c3,c4 are different classes. The classes are imbalanced so I want that to be taken into account in the calculation (not use balanced class weights).

Comment: In `sklearn` you could define your own `criterion` class and then pass it to your  classifier, see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10251). `gini` and `entropy` are defined [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx) and you could use them as a template.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question with more details. From the `gini` code it's not clear how to implement my criteria. Maybe `( sum_total[1] + sum_total[2] -  sum_total[3])/[2* sqrt(sum_total[2] + sum_total[4])]` but what does `weighted_n_node_samples` do?